# How to check the items in array from a jsonschema, python3

Tags: python-3.x, jsonschema

I have a json schema. This is in a file named `input_schema.py`.

```
input_scheme = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "company": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "founder": {"type": "string"},
                "email": {"type": "string"},
            },
        },
        "branch_locations": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": [
                {
                    "street": {"type": "string"},
                    "house_number": {"type": "number"},
                    "city": {"type": "string"},
                    "country": {"type": "string"},
                },
            ],
        },
    },
    "additionalProperties": False,
}
```

And I have input data in another python file.

```
from jsonschema import validate
from input_schema import input_scheme


data = {
    "company": {
        "founder": "me",
        "email": "me@mycompany.com"
    },
    "branch_locations": [
        {
            "street": "Street A",
            "house_number": 1,
            "cityyyyyyy": "City A",
            "country": "Country A",
        },
    ],
}


validate(data, schema=input_scheme)
```

The `data` has a strange item name `"cityyyyyyy"`. This is an invalid case, but the `validate` function from `jsonschema` package cannot detect it.

I think it is the `input_scheme` that is not correct. Could you please help me with it? How to modify the schema definition? By the way, I need these 4 items (and only these 4 items) of a branch location: "street", "house_number", "city", "country".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `items` keyword should be a schema. Because "street", "house_number", etc are not JSON Schema keywords, they get ignored. and no validation happens on the items in the "branch_location" array.

Here's what the value of the `items` keyword should look like in your example.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street": { "type": "string" },
    "house_number": { "type": "number" },
    "city": { "type": "string" },
    "country": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```